# How can I use regular expression capture groups in API Gateway Response mapping

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to map some data from within the exception thrown by a Lambda to the API Gateway response, but am having problems.

For example, I have a Lambda that can throw an exception like this:

```
User some-user-id exists: java.lang.IllegalStateException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User some-user-id exists
at u.c.c.e.s.lambda.user.handler.RegisterNewUserRequestHandler.handleRequest(RegisterNewUserRequestHandler.java:68)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ConditionalCheckFailedException; Request ID: UONMOKNKVSEIL8EI6T6NVPODOJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1630)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1302)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3082)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3058)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeUpdateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2778)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2753)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doUpdateItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:854)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$2.executeLowLevelRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:594)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:733)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:623)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.save(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:128)
at uk.co.claritysoftware.exam.slammr.lambda.user.handler.RegisterNewUserRequestHandler.saveNewUserIfNotExists(RegisterNewUserRequestHandler.java:97)
at uk.co.claritysoftware.exam.slammr.lambda.user.handler.RegisterNewUserRequestHandler.handleRequest(RegisterNewUserRequestHandler.java:63)
```

I've written a regex to match the error message, but I'd like to extract the user id from the error; and I was hoping to use a capturing group, then reference it in the mapping, like this:

[image]

But it doesn't work - the `$1` appears to be treated as a string literal.

As a work around, I am mapping the exception message with this mapping template:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "message" : "$inputRoot.errorMessage"
}
```

But this is a compromise as it maps the native Lambda message which, whilst in this case is close enough, feels wrong because I'm reliant on the Lambda throwing an exception with a reasonably sensible exception message, and it feels akin to exposing native exception messages to the front end which we know is bad practice.

Any ideas how I can do this?

---

#### Edits

In answer to the questions asked in the comments:

1. The (i) icon shows this when hovered over:
   [image]
2. Trying to escape the group reference with either `\1` or `\$1` both result in `\1` or `\$1` coming back in the response as string literals.

Comment: What if you use `\1`?

Comment: what does the hint (i) icon next to Lambda Error Regex say?

Comment: I think this feature is not available.